# Parallel Real-Time Scheduling of DAGs in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, tmux, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

**How To Run/Instantiate a Dag(Airflow) on  Parallel basis  for multiple categories ?**

For example :
 I have an airflow(DAG) which i run on regular basis
how i can schedule dag to run on parallel basis on different **Batchnames** (in parallet):

1. run the dag for batch1 (pass the batch name in args)
2. run the dag for batch2 (pass the batch name in args) should run parallel with **1**
   .
   .
   .

And so on

I used environment varibale to pass **Batchnames** and then ran dag in parallel using multiple **tmux** session on server but it was messed up.

Is there any better approach that I may use and with which I may save time and run dag for multiple batchnames in parallel?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Since airflow runs python classes representing graphs of bash-shell commands, you can do this within airflow by creating two independent DAGs.  Here's a slight modification to the [tutorial](http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/tutorial.html),

```
dag = DAG(dag_id='batch')
task = [ BashOperator(
             task_id='templated',
             bash_command=templated_command,
             params={'batch_name': batch_name},
             dag=dag)
        for batch_name in ["batch one", "batch two"]]

dag.add_task(task[0])
dag.add_task(task[1])
```

Since there is no dependency, they should run in parallel as long as airflow has been set up that way.  If you need to set a shell environment variable, add VAR={{ params.batch_name }} somewhere in the template.

Assuming your program uses sys.argv, you could also use normal job control to launch:

```
python ~/airflow/dags/tutorial.py "batch one" &
python ~/airflow/dags/tutorial.py "batch two" &
wait
```